# Efficient way for counting html characters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I'm trying to find total character count (offset) from a starting to selected/clicked element/text. For example,

```
<div>
  <span>text 1</span>
  <span>text 2</span>
  <span>text 3</span>
</div>
```

if someone clicks on `text 2`, I need to count total characters of all elements before `text 2`.

***So here is my approach:***

> (The problem with my code is, it crashes the browser if there are
> lots of nested elements, so what could be other efficient way around?)

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root")



root.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const startOffset = selection.getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
  const node = selection.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
  const totalOffset = countTotalOffset(node, startOffset);
  
    alert('total offset: ' + totalOffset )

})


function countTotalOffset(node, offset) {

  if (!node.previousSibling) {
    if (!node.parentElement) return offset;
    if (node.parentElement.id === "root") return offset
    return countTotalOffset(node.parentElement, offset)
  }
  
  const _offset = !node.previousSibling.textContent ? 0 : node.previousSibling.textContent.length;
  return countTotalOffset(node.previousSibling, offset + _offset);

}
```

```html
<h2>Click on any list item to get offset count</h2>
<ul id="root">
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>
      list 4
      <ul>
        <li>list 5</li>
        <li>list 6</li>
        <li>list 7</li>
        <li>list 8
            <ul>
              <li>list 9</li>
              <li>list 10</li>
              <li>list 11</li>
              <li>list 12
          
                <ul>
                  <li><span>list 13</span> <span>list 13</span></li>
                  <li>list 14</li>
                  <li>list 15
                    <ul>
                      <li>list 16</li>
                      <li><span>list 17</span> <span>list 17</span></li>
                      <li>list 18</li>
                      <li>list 19</li>
                      <li><span>list 20</span> <span>list 20</span></li>
                      <li>list 21</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>list 22</li>
                  <li>list 23</li>
                  <li>list 24</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>list 25</li>
              <li>list 26</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>list 27</li>
        <li>list 28</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list 29</li>
    <li>list 30</li>
    
  </ul>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you're trying to count

Comment: total characters from starting to clicked element. @CristianTraìna

Comment: What's "starting"? Is it the element root? By HTML characters you mean just the text or also the markup code itself?

Comment: starting means root, and not the markup only text content. @CristianTraìna
My current code is working, but it crashes the browser if there are lots of nested markup

Comment: @CristianTraìna you can run my code an click on any list item to get the result

Comment: II took a look at your code, but I still don't understand. From what you wrote, I was expecting to click on "text 1" and get 0 as an answer (as there are no elements before it., but I get 7. I don't get what's that number.

Comment: @RaphaelAleixo I'm not counting element, I'm counting the character inside element

Comment: @DelowarHosain, I still don't get it. The first element `<li>list 1</li>` has 6 characters inside it, or am I still getiing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not beautiful, but you can try this.
It's about adding a unique placeholder text to your element, then use "innerText" to get all the document text and count everything until you meet the placeholder. The only problem is that it introduces a "magic word".

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root")



root.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  const selection = window.getSelection()
  const originalText = selection.anchorNode.textContent
  const placeholder = "$$$_placeholder_$$$"
  selection.anchorNode.textContent = originalText + placeholder
  const charsCount = root.innerText.split(placeholder)[0].length
  selection.anchorNode.textContent = originalText
  
  alert(charsCount)
})
```

```html
<ul id="root">
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>
      list 4
      <ul>
        <li>list 5</li>
        <li>list 6</li>
        <li>list 7</li>
        <li>list 8
            <ul>
              <li>list 9</li>
              <li>list 10</li>
              <li>list 11</li>
              <li>list 12
          
                <ul>
                  <li><span>list 13</span> <span>list 13</span></li>
                  <li>list 14</li>
                  <li>list 15
                    <ul>
                      <li>list 16</li>
                      <li><span>list 17</span> <span>list 17</span></li>
                      <li>list 18</li>
                      <li>list 19</li>
                      <li><span>list 20</span> <span>list 20</span></li>
                      <li>list 21</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li>list 22</li>
                  <li>list 23</li>
                  <li>list 24</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>list 25</li>
              <li>list 26</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>list 27</li>
        <li>list 28</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>list 29</li>
    <li>list 30</li>
    
  </ul>
```

Comment: wow, I really appreciate the way you solve it. I tried this approach but I didn't think about the placeholder text. Thank you so much.